can i run python code in c++ or c++ in python so that the speed is the same?
I have code that is written in Python and code that is written in C++. Now I want to compare the two in terms of the speed of the algorithms. It is common knowledge that C++ is faster than Python. Can I somehow run my Python code in the C++ environment or my C++ code in the Python environment?
I searched but I didn´t found somethign, which helped me.

Maybe you can find similar code among these benchmarks https://programming-language-benchmarks.vercel.app/python-vs-cpp

Try an online compiler that supports both languages like https://onecompiler.com/cpp/429yktfz5

Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23500173/is-this-a-valid-method-for-cpu-time-comparison-between-c-and-python

there are ways to get Python code compiled and have it execute comparably fast. that's not for beginners though. you need to learn more about computers and programming fundamentals before you're ready to understand how that works.

Maybe if there's a compiler that can do this, but I don't know any.
You can always write some example code that does the same thing in both python and C++, then use a timer to track when each code completes and compare the times?

Take a look at 11l or pythran ...

No, it doesn't work like that, the two languages are completely separate.
C++ is compiled, which is why you need to first run a command like g++ to turn it into an executable which you can run, whereas Python is interpreted (you tell python to directly execute a .py file).
If you want to compare two different algorithms, you should write them both in C++ or both in Python.

No, you cannot benchmark the C++ code by running in Python or vise versa. You have to use the respective compiler and interpreter and find the time taken individually and then compare it.
